# Unzip a file without the aggressive MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I'm building a small app in Flutter targeting Android 30+ that needs to download and unzip a collection of files into a directory.

Everything works as expected when targetting SDK 29 and below, but when moving to 30+ I get permission denied unless I start using `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` which seems a bit overkill to unzip a file.

I've tried downloading the file into a number of different directories (Phone Tmp, Application support, and Application Document) to see if that helps but no go.

Is there some other kind of permission I can use or another way of solving this?

Comment: The `Documents` directory seems a good place for this operation and you won't need `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for SDK 30 and above

Comment: I've given that a go but am still getting Permission denied, are you able to provide a link to details that it should work?

Comment: Can you kindly add what you tried because I'm not well versed with Flutter but I can suggest some changes

Answer (score -1):

Use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();` or `getCacheDir()` you will not need a permission.

**Example:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Reading and Writing Files',
      home: FlutterDemo(storage: CounterStorage()),
    ),
  );
}

class CounterStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<int> readCounter() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      final contents = await file.readAsString();

      return int.parse(contents);
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return 0
      return 0;
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString('$counter');
  }
}

class FlutterDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterDemo({Key? key, required this.storage}) : super(key: key);

  final CounterStorage storage;

  @override
  _FlutterDemoState createState() => _FlutterDemoState();
}

class _FlutterDemoState extends State<FlutterDemo> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.storage.readCounter().then((int value) {
      setState(() {
        _counter = value;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<File> _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });

    // Write the variable as a string to the file.
    return widget.storage.writeCounter(_counter);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Reading and Writing Files'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Button tapped $_counter time${_counter == 1 ? '' : 's'}.',
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect and you've misread my question. I can create, read, and delete files but cannot modify existing files with those permissions.

Comment: @ChrisTurner referring to your question you don't need to modify any file. extracting a zip file does not require modifying it!!